# Couldn't match type Maybe ([a], a0)

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors

I can't understand why I'm getting this error message:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘Maybe ([a], a0)’
          with ‘String -> Maybe ([a1], String)’
```

My code :

```
type Parse a = String -> Maybe(a, String)

parseMany :: Parse a -> Parse [a]
parseMany p str = case p str of 
                    Nothing -> Just ([], str)
                    Just (z, str') -> case parseMany (z str') of
                                    Just (c, str'') ->  Just ((z : c), show (str''))
```

Comment: What is `(z str')` supposed to do? `z` seems to be the result, not a function that can be used.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem z is a Parse so ```Maybe(a, String)```
That's what my mate told me

Comment: but with an expresion like `z str'` that means that `z` should be a function that takes a string as parameter.

Comment: @scorval No, `z` has type `a`, not `Parse something`.

Comment: Ha ok I totally misunderstood the principle, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `z str'` makes no sense, `z` is an object of type `a`, not a function that can take a `String` parameter.

You can use the same base parser `p` to parse the next item:

```
parseMany :: Parse a -> Parse [a]
parseMany p str = case p str of 
    Nothing -> Just ([], str)
    Just (z, str') -> case parseMany p str' of
        Just (c, str'') ->  Just ((z : c), str'')
        Nothing -> Nothing
```

If we have a simple parser like:

```
myParser :: Parse Int
myParser ('a':xs) = Just (1, xs)
myParser _ = Nothing
```

then it will parse a list of `'a'`s to:

```
ghci> parseMany myParser "aaaaaa"
Just ([1,1,1,1,1,1],"")
```

Comment: Haaaa ok thanks all, I totaly missunderstood the principle...
Have a good day !